# Delete body box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, jbox2d

Could anyone tell me why this is returning the error

'AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed'

//mouseJoint collision callback

```
private QueryCallback queryCallback = new QueryCallback() {

    @Override
    public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {


        if(fixture.getBody() == chest){

            //add to remove list

            bodiesToRemove.add(chest);

        }

        if (fixture.testPoint(tmp.x, tmp.y)){


            reportFixture = fixture.getBody();
        }


        if (!fixture.testPoint(tmp.x, tmp.y))
            return false;

        //assigning bodyB to fixture 
        jointDef.bodyB = fixture.getBody();
        jointDef.target.set(fixture.getBody().getWorldCenter());

        //jointDef.target.set(tmp.x, tmp.y);// initial target point coincide with body anchor

        joint = (MouseJoint) world.createJoint(jointDef);// creating the join the physics world
        return false;
    }

};
```

//main rendering loop

```
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       //code clears the screen with the given RGB colour (black)
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f );
    Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );


     stage.setCamera(camera);               
     stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());




    camera.position.x= chest.getPosition().x;


    camera.update();

     stage.draw();



    world.step(1 / 60f, 8, 3);
    renderer.render(world, camera.combined);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

// this is the code that is causing the error when I try to delete a body

```
    if(bodiesToRemove != null){

    for(int i = 0; i <bodiesToRemove.size; i++){

        Body b = bodiesToRemove.get(i);

        if(b != null){
           world.destroyBody(b);
           b.setUserData(null);
           b = null;
        }
        bodiesToRemove.clear();
    }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I've changed this and it work's(pasted below), if anyone would like to explain the right way to do this or if this is the correct way that would be helpful.
I just added a boolean to prevent it from destroying the joint

```
// ////////////////// TOUCH EVENT ///////////////////////////////
//Called when a finger was lifted or a mouse button was released.
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    //If no mouseJoint do nothing

    System.out.println("touch" + (screenY*0.01f));
    System.out.println("touch" + (screenX*0.01f));



    if (joint == null)
        return false;


    //When user is not touching Screen destroy the
    //mouseJoint/set to null
    if(ran == false){

    world.destroyJoint(joint);
    joint = null;}


    ran = false;
    return true;
}



////////////////////////////////
```

/////////////////////////////////

```
    if(!world.isLocked() && world.getBodyCount() > 0 ){

        for(int i = 0; i <bodiesToRemove.size; i++){

            Body b = bodiesToRemove.get(i);

            if(b == null){
                bodiesToRemove.removeIndex(i);
                continue;
            }
            world.destroyBody(b);
            ran = true;
            bodiesToRemove.removeIndex(i);

        }

        }else{

            bodiesToRemove.clear();
        }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2):

Box2D throws some odd errors, this is not one of them.

I assume you are using LibGDX, basically what is happening is a crash due to Box2D (I also assume it pops up saying "java or whatever has stopped responding"), this error you are seeing is thrown when the app exits while OpenAL is closing streams and cleaning up resources. Don't worry about that too much.

Ensure you are checking of the world is locked before destroying bodies, it usually throws an error and prints a clear message telling you this, depending on the way you are removing bodies.

```
if(!world.isLocked())
    // do clean up code here
```

You don't need to clean up the variable inside local scope, or clear the userdata inside the body as the body as it will no longer exist in reference (unless you have it stored somewhere else).

So the proper code would be something like this:

```
if(!world.isLocked()){
    for(int i = bodiesToRemove.size - 1; i--){
        Body b = bodiesToRemove.get(i);
        if(b == null){
            bodiesToRemove.removeAt(i);
            continue;
        }
        world.destroyBody(b);
        bodiesToRemove.removeAt(i);
    }
}
```

You are also clearing a list during iteration, not a good idea.

**EDIT**

The only other thing I can think of that is causing this problem is trying to delete a body that is not actually in the worlds body list.

Try the following:

```
// Ensure world is not locked AND that there is even bodies in the world
if(!world.isLocked() && world.getBodyCount() > 0){
    for(int i = bodiesToRemove.size - 1; i--){
        Body b = bodiesToRemove.get(i);
        if(b == null){
            bodiesToRemove.removeAt(i);
            continue;
        }
        world.destroyBody(b);
        bodiesToRemove.removeAt(i);
    }
}else{
    // There is no bodies in the world, so the bodies in our list are just
    // random memory hogs, leave them for the GC by clearing the list
    bodiesToRemove.clear();
}
```

**EDIT**

As stated by the OP, the problem lies with this block of code:

private QueryCallback queryCallback = new QueryCallback() {

```
@Override
public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {
    if(fixture.getBody() == chest){
        //add to remove list
        bodiesToRemove.add(chest);
    }
    if (fixture.testPoint(tmp.x, tmp.y)){
        reportFixture = fixture.getBody();
    }
    if (!fixture.testPoint(tmp.x, tmp.y))
        return false;
    //assigning bodyB to fixture 
    jointDef.bodyB = fixture.getBody();
    jointDef.target.set(fixture.getBody().getWorldCenter());
    //jointDef.target.set(tmp.x, tmp.y);
    joint = (MouseJoint) world.createJoint(jointDef);
    return false;
}
```

};

More specifically, this line:

```
    joint = (MouseJoint) world.createJoint(jointDef);
```

The query callback is triggered during a world step. **In Box2D, you can not create or destroy bodies, fixtures, and joints during the world step.**

You have to create it outside this method, the simplest way to do it is via a flag. Set a flag to true and store the instance of the fixture somewhere and handle it outside in the game loop using said flag and fixture.

Comment: the first thing I thought was that it was for wanting to delete a Body that is being used, but seeing AL, discard it, my question is, box2d throws that error when related to AL? although logic would have it send if the application to crash, I wanted to ask if you only throws this error "AL lib ...." or accompanied by others, to know, never me to last

Comment: Box2D does not throw that error, the actual application does. It is getting thrown due to a crash, most Box2D crashes result in the application hanging and then CTD, therefore the AL library has no time to clean up. So it prints this error.

Comment: thanks for your response did not occur to me, seeing AL lib discard what he believed, in principle haha, thanks for your clarification, I think your answer is correct I delete mine

Comment: you can say in reply, that you be more clear, you should use the code that you mention or something similar before updating the world, but it's just an idea, I vote for upvote

Comment: I've tried to copy and paste your code 

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  
  if(!world.isLocked()){
   
      for(int i = 0; i <bodiesToRemove.size; i++){
       
          Body b = bodiesToRemove.get(i);
          if(b == null){
              bodiesToRemove.removeIndex(i);
              continue;
          }
          world.destroyBody(b);
          bodiesToRemove.removeIndex(i);
      }
  }
  
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


I still get the same error ,thanks for responding .

Comment: OK, then the last thing I can think of that you are trying to delete a body that is either null, already destroyed or a floating reference (as in just kicking about in some collection outside of world). I will update my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to work with the edit either, here is my full code ' http://pastebin.com/3fV7iKw2 ' , I know its not neat/using everything I'm declaring . I just wanted to create a working example for the correct way to delete body's in Box2d. If anyone has an example of this or can correct mine I would appreciate it.

Comment: I've added an edit it works when I remove 'world.destroyJoint(joint);' from the touchUp method. I do not know why though ? Or how to change it whilst including that section of code.

Comment: Ah never noticed that, you can't create or destroy anything Box2D during the world step. So the world is queried during a step and that callback is triggered, so you are creating a joint during world simulation. Instead you want that callback to set a flag or something, then have it handled outside the query.